# Can multiple versions of CUPS co-exist on a RHEL box?

Tags: rpm, cups, rhel5

I have a RHEL 5.8 box that is running CUPS 1.4. I need to test CUPS 1.7 on it but I don't want to remove 1.4 as I may need to install it again. My question is: can multiple versions of CUPS co-exist on the same RHEL box? I understand that I don't want both running at the same time. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I asked the same question at https://unix.stackexchange.com and this is the answer I got:

"If you install one version from source then you can have two versions and then run them independently. Another option is to run a different version in a docker container. This way, both can run at the same time. –"

Thanks to @RamanSailopal